# Color de Td segun valor

Tags: jquery, html, css

tengo una tabla HTML con dos columna(descripción y valor), y necesito que cada fila de pinte de un color especifico dependiendo del valor que tenga la columna "valor".

Con jQuery estoy usando esto:

```
$("#mitabla td:last-child:contains(5)")
    .parents("tr")
    .css("background-color", "verde");
```

pero si hago lo mismo para cada valor(lo valores posibles son conocidos, solo números entre 1-10) no funciona, y solo colorea según la primera condición que haya escrito.

como se puede hacer esto, con algún `if` o `switch`?

Comment: daniel2017, muestranos un ejemplo del html de tu tabla para poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de solucionarlo podría ser la siguiente:

- Defines cada regla que aplica a cada caso (`valor 1, 2, 3, etc.`)
- **[Opcional]** Si las filas se cargan dinámicamente, deberías mover estas reglas a una función (`ejemplo: colorearFilas`) y ejecutar dicha función cada vez se se actualiza la tabla.

Ejemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#table td:last-child:contains(1)').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
  $('#table td:last-child:contains(2)').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'blue');
  $('#table td:last-child:contains(3)').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'green');
  // Así sucesivamente hasta llegar al 10
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Descripción</th>
      <th>Valor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Algo 1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Algo 2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Algo 3</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Algo 4</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Algo 5</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: gracias, es lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 0):

Una vez que cargas la pagina la tabla cambia de valor?

Si la respuesta es no, podrias usar algo asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function() {
$( "#tiobeTable tbody tr td.ratings" ).each( function( index ) {
if ( parseFloat( $( this ).text() ) > 10 ) {
$( this ).addClass( "highlight" );
}
});
$( "#tiobeTable tbody tr td.delta" ).each( function( index ) {
if ( parseFloat( $( this ).text() ) < 0 ) {
$( this ).addClass( "highlight-negative" );
}
});
});
</script>
```

Si no se entiende avisame y te lo explico mejor. Te paso el link de donde lo saque, que tiene mas info que puede serte util. Saludos.

https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/showhide-rows-and-highlighting-cells